# PHP application in cloud sites not able to access the memcached running at cloud server - rackspace

Tags: php, yii, memcached, rackspace

I am running a php application(Yii) in rackspace cloud sites. I have installed a memcached server at rackspace cloud server which is running. The problem, i am not able to access the memcache. I am getting the following errors

`Memcache::get() [<a href='memcache.get'>memcache.get</a>]: Server xx.xx.xxx.xxx (tcp 11211) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
(10060)`

```
netstat -an | grep ":11211"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*          LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                              
udp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*
```

Please find the cache configuration at `main.php`

```
'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
        'servers'=>array(
            array('host'=>' xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 'port'=>11211, 'weight'=>60),
        ),
    ),
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening port 11211 via iptables? I don't know which distribution you are using, but here are a couple of tutorials:

- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-essentials-3-basic-cloud-server-security#iptables
- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/sample-iptables-ruleset

Also, since you are with Rackspace you will likely be able to reach an engineer who could help via the Live Chat. I've always found them very helpful indeed!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed centOS 6 distribution. I ll go through the links and get back to you. I had chat with the support team, but the solution was not helpful.